# Erro ao passar AddDays em expressão Lambda

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, linq, expressões-lambda

Nessa lambda, me dá o erro abaixo, quando entra no IF:

```
var resultado = webDB.T_ControleColetor
                            .Where(cn => cn.CNPJ == cnpj)
                            .Where(dt => dt.DataControle == DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
                            .Select(x => x.DataControle);

            if(resultado.Count() > 0)
            {
                result = 1;
            }
```

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Como eu resolvo isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilize [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ou [DbFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) para tal expressão:

*Diferença é que **DbFunctions** está em `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions` e é para versão 6+ do [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework), abaixo utilize **EntityFunctions** que estã em `System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions`*

*Com EntityFunctions*

```
DateTime data = DateTime.Now.Date;
var resultado = webDB.T_ControleColetor
                            .Where(cn => cn.CNPJ == cnpj)
                            .Where(dt => dt.DataControle == EntityFunctions.AddDays(Data, - 1))
                            .Select(x => x.DataControle);

            if(resultado.Count() > 0)
            {
                result = 1;
            }
```

---

*Com DbFunctions*

```
DateTime data = DateTime.Now.Date;
var resultado = webDB.T_ControleColetor
                            .Where(cn => cn.CNPJ == cnpj)
                            .Where(dt => dt.DataControle == DbFunctions.AddDays(Data, - 1))
                            .Select(x => x.DataControle);

            if(resultado.Count() > 0)
            {
                result = 1;
            }
```

*Referência:*

- [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [DbFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)
- [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework)

Comment: Eu ontem à noite, consegui fazer com EntityFunctions, mas vou considerar a resposta sua, FCCDias.