# Compara campo DateTime em uma lambda apenas a parte Data

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Nessa lambda, resultado praticamente será sempre nulo, pois eu dei um GetDate() direto no banco e quando isso acontece, eu gravo Data e Hora. Como eu faço nessa lambda passar somente Data e comparar com DateTime.Now apenas a data? Tentei usar alguns recursos do C# na lambda e não aceitou.

```
var resultado = db.T_PDV
                .Where(a => a.DataCadastro == DateTime.Now)
                .Select(i => new { i.CNPJ})
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Pnet isso é duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14857/erro-ao-passar-adddays-em-expressao-lambda/14862#14862 olha eu já respondi isso!

Comment: Não é duplicata, Harry. Porque aqui eu gostaria de saber como eu passo apenas o campo Data sem a parte hora. Lá fala de outra coisa, ainda que com campos data.

Comment: Tudo bem então, mas, vamos ver como a comunidade vai entender isso... por mim tudo bem, e a resposta foi dada!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilize [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ou [DbFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) para tal expressão:

Diferença é que [DbFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) está em `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions` e é para versão 6+ do Entity Framework, abaixo utilize [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que está em `System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions`

No caso especifico use [`DbFunctions.TruncateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) ou [`EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.truncatetime%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) dependendo da versão do [`Entity Framework`](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) para ele deixar somente o valor de Data. Também na variavel sua coloca o valor de Data igual `var dta = DateTime.Now.Date;` trazendo também somente Data sem hora.

```cs
var dta = DateTime.Now.Date;    
var resultado = db.T_PDV.Where(a => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.DataCadastro) == dta)
                .Select(i => new { i.CNPJ})
                .ToList();
```

---

```cs
var dta = DateTime.Now.Date;    
var resultado = db.T_PDV.Where(a => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.DataCadastro) == dta)
                    .Select(i => new { i.CNPJ})
                    .ToList();
```

Nesse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14857/erro-ao-passar-adddays-em-expressao-lambda/14862#14862), tem um bem parecido mas, utilizando outro método. Esse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14857/erro-ao-passar-adddays-em-expressao-lambda/14862#14862) server com item de referências.

Comment: Harry, tentei adicionar o namespace dessa metodo DBFunction e não consigo. Eu só tenho System.Data.Entity e nesse namespace não tenho o DBFunction. Usei o EntityFunction e dá que é obsoleto

Comment: Não foi isso não. É que eu peguei o primeiro using sugerido por ele e não tinha o DBFunctions. Usei esse using e funcionou: using System.Data.Objects;